# How to preprocess Bootstrap region

Tags: panels, theming

I am using Panels Bootstrap Layouts. I insert bootstrap_twocol_stacked into the $content region.

I'd like to be able to access regions of that Bootstrap layout (Top, Left, Right, Bottom) in my page.tpl.php template to restructure the HTML code, but I only seem to have an access to the content. $page['content']['system_main']['content']['#markup'] variable when run e.g.

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

only contains rendered HTML code and does not give me option to access Bootstrap data as array, like $page['content']['***']['top'].

I tried to look for a preprocess hook (probably one of the panels module function), but could not figure out which one.

Any hints?

[image]

What I am trying to do is to move the bootstrap region to the same hierarchy level in the page.tpl.php as other page regions, see the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, if somebody is interested:

create new section in your theme, call it e.g. bottom-section and use this preprocess hook to move the content of the bottom pane to bottom-section section

```
function theme_preprocess_panels_pane(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['pane']->panel == 'bottom') {
    // Move to a region
    drupal_add_region_content('bottom-section', $variables['content']['#markup']);
    // Delete the pane from the panel
    $variables = array();
  }
}
```